# MariaDB in Docker Compose doesn't response to inner shell command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, mariadb, centos

I'm using

```
CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111
Docker version 23.0.1
Docker Compose version 2.3.4
```

And my docker compose is insists of images like nginx, was(gunicorn and django), mariadb.

**My docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  web:
    image: python:3.9
    hostname: web
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_web
    volumes:
      - ./facility_iot:/service
      - ./tmp:/tmp
    # command: sh -c "cd /service && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    command: sh -c "cd /service && gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /tmp --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout=60 config.wsgi:application"
    # command: sh -c "cd /service && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate"

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    hostname: mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    cpu_count: 4
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: [PASSWORD]
      TZ: Asia/Seoul
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mariadb/init.sql:/init.sql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: --init-file /init.sql

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    cpu_count: 4
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - web
      - grafana
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/static:/static
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    hostname: grafana
    container_name: grafana
    cpu_count: 1
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/conf:/usr/share/grafana/conf
      # - ./grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana
```

**My Problem :**

I want to get into MariaDB container after I build with

```
docker compose up --build -d
```

It works properly with

```
docker exec -it mariadb /bin/bash
```

But it has no response when I tried with

```
docker compose exec mariadb bash
```

not just mariadb, but everything.

I can get inside of the container, but if i want to do some commands, it just stopped with no response like below.

```
[root@DST iot-project]# docker compose mariadb bash
root@mariadb:/# ls
```

```
[root@DST iot-project]# docker compose mariadb bash
root@mariadb:/# mysql -u root -p
```

```
[root@DST iot-project]# docker compose mariadb bash
root@mariadb:/# mysql -u root -p
^C^C^CERRO[0006] got 3 SIGTERM/SIGINTs, forcing shutdown
```

Really nothing I can do..

**My Question :**

1. How can i fix this?
2. I'm just curious why it is different. (docker exec  VS  docker compose exec)

I just expected 'docker exec' and 'docker compose exec' works same..

Comment: Are you sure that `docker compose` is correct and should not be `docker-compose`?

Comment: Yes, `docker-compose` is V1, `docker compose` is V2. So... i used `docker compose` until now... Am i doing wrong with this?!

Comment: How would you get a shell inside your database server without using Docker?  I'm guessing you'd more likely interact with it using `mysql` directly; if the database is operational then I wouldn't worry about debugging tools like `docker exec` not working well.

Comment: Well, database is working well, and i can debug it with `docker exec` command but not `docker compose exec`. I'm.. just curious why is it different.

Comment: I tried re-install, but i noticed my docker-compose is not the version recently updated. But maybe CentOS8's docker compose version is limited to 2.3.4 while docker can be installed updated release... Maybe this mismatch caused this problem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, now i found that docker compose V2, v2.3.4 has a problem.

[Check this issue.](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9315)

I've re-installed docker several times, but there was always docker compose v2.3.4.
Maybe, in my OS, the most recent version which can be installed is 2.3.4...

So, i moved it to 2.3.3. Then this is finally fixed.

I need to use 2.3.3 until the newer version released...